# The mysteries of extending the WPF animation classes

Tags: wpf, animation, freezable

Silverlight has a property on its animation timelines (like DoubleAnimation) called EasingFunction which allows you to specify a function with which to interpolate two values. Even though it's coming in .NET 4, I'd like to port this to 3.5. After reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163397.aspx), it seems pretty doable, but I'm having a weird issue.

I'm extending DoubleAnimation like so:

```
class EasingDoubleAnimation : DoubleAnimation
{
    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new EasingDoubleAnimation();
    }

    protected override double GetCurrentValueCore( double defaultOriginValue, double defaultDestinationValue, AnimationClock animationClock )
    {
        Debug.WriteLine( animationClock.CurrentProgress.Value );
        return base.GetCurrentValueCore( defaultOriginValue, defaultDestinationValue, animationClock );
    }

    public EasingFunctionBase EasingFunction
    {
        get { return ( EasingFunctionBase ) GetValue( EasingFunctionProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( EasingFunctionProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EasingFunctionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "EasingFunction", typeof( EasingFunctionBase ), typeof( EasingDoubleAnimation ),
            new PropertyMetadata( null ) );
}
```

Note that it's not doing anything interesting other than adding a new property.

And then I can use it in some code:

```
Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
EasingDoubleAnimation ease = new EasingDoubleAnimation();
//ease.EasingFunction = new BackEase();
Storyboard.SetTarget( ease, MyTarget );
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty( ease, new PropertyPath( "(Canvas.Left)" ) );
ease.To = 100;
ease.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 3 );
sb.Children.Add( ease );
sb.Begin();
```

That code runs the animation just fine.

But, if I uncomment the line that sets EasingFunction, the animation no longer runs. My CreateInstanceCore method gets called, but GetCurrentValue is never called. Weird?

Answer (score 1):

Just gonna take a shot in the dark here. Try changing the type of the property to a simple type (`int` / `string`). I suspect it may have something to do with the fact that your property type is `EasingFunctionBase` and you're trying to freeze the instance.

Comment: I actually experimented with that before posting, and found that as long as I had simple property types, everything worked fine. It looks like you just can't have complex property types on Freezable objects.

"So how does Silverlight 3 do it?" I ask, and I find in Reflector that DoubleAnimation in SL3 is actually not Freezable like it is in WPF. Seems like I might not be able to do what I want to do in the obvious way.

Comment: Unless I make EasingFunctionBase also Freezable. Then it works, though I won't be able to change properties on it later... but that may be ok in my case. Thanks for the reply.